# JavaScript Changing HTML Content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with a string inside of it. I want to change that string if something specific happens. I am not sure why but I can't get the string to change at all even if there is no conditional. I am very rusty to JavaScript so any advice would be appreciated, I am slowly getting back to the basics.

```
<div class="cell text-center" id="changeString"> Report has not yet been pulled for this organization.</div>

var bananas = true;      
if (bananas = true){
    document.getElementById('changeString').innerHTML = "You have successfully run the report.";
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I have also tried putting the JS into a function and calling it in the div with `onload="methodName"`.

Comment: Missing quotes in `getElementById(changeString)` and the `=` in the if should be `==` or `===`. `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: `changeString` is a variable that refers to the DOM element. `getElementById` however expects to be passed a string value. So either do `changeString.innerHTML = ...` or `document.getElementById('changeString').innerHTML = ...`

Comment: Good catch thank you. `var bananas = true;    
console.log(bananas);
   if (bananas == true){ 
  document.getElementById("changeString").innerHTML = "You have successfully run the report.";
    }` This still doesn't work but I can see in the console that it is returning true.

Comment: Make sure you run the JavaScript after the div was loaded. It should work. See https://jsfiddle.net/jkdmzvo4/

Comment: if you run in it in html add `script` tags https://jsfiddle.net/maio/8qt9fzjr/2/

Comment: Umm... not enough [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I know this should work. I am writing HTML in Visualforce which I think might be throwing it off. Even when I copy exactly the JSFiddle you wrote, I get no response.

Answer (score 3):

Just like **@j08691** mentioned in **[the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882872/javascript-changing-html-content/39883061#comment-67052737)** you should add quotes to `getElementById()` :

```
document.getElementById("changeString").innerHTML = "You have successfully run the report."
________________________^____________^
```

And to use `==` or `===` in your condition for comparison instead of equal `=` that used for assignment:

```
if (bananas === true){
```

And it will work as you could see below.

Hope this helps.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var bananas = true;

  if (bananas === true){
    document.getElementById("changeString").innerHTML = "You have successfully run the report."
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="cell text-center" id="changeString"> Report has not yet been pulled for this organization.</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I believe I am running into an issue with my IDE, your code and the JSFiddle provided all work, just not with my current settings for some reason.

Comment: You're welcome, have you tried to add code inside ready function? try my update..

Comment: That strange have you tried to add an alert or `console.log()` to make sure that this part of your code is reached?

Comment: yes, and it is logging in the console. It is so strange...my only last guess is that it is because I am writing HTML in a Visualforce page and they don't like each other. I already have about 800 lines that have no errors so I am just as confused as you are!